# Missing "rel" in Spring HATEOAS HAL responses

Tags: java, spring, spring-hateoas, hal

I am looking at the HAL links which are returned by Spring HATEOAS. The links look like

```
"_links" : {
"self" : {
  "href" : "http://localhost:8765/data-service/dataObjects"
},
"profile" : {
  "href" : "http://localhost:8765/data-service/profile/dataObjects"
},
"search" : {
  "href" : "http://localhost:8765/data-service/dataObjects/search"
}
```

They seem to be missing "rel" in favor of the link name. My question is: are the links in HATEOAS response  weblinks?  If they are they, must be compliant with [RFC 5988](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988). According to it "rel" is not optional.

Comment: You have a HAL document and ask about another standard. That makes no sense. _"They seem to be missing "rel" in favor of the link name"_ The "link name" **is** the relation.

Answer (score 0):

The document returned is compliant with the HAL spec.

See http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html for spec and examples.

Comment: Don't understand the downvote. Question is about rendering links in HAL and why is "rel" missing. I have cited the HAL spec, where links in the body do not contain the "rel" text, but instead, the name of the rel.